# Миграция базы данных MySQL на Azure

Tags: mysql, база-данных, azure-websites

Добрый день.

Возникла проблема при миграции базы данных MySQL с одного хостинга на Azure хостинг (ClearDB). Предварительно я развернул Acquia Drupal 7 on MySQL на Azure. Используя Kudu, поставил phpMyAdmin, удалил старую базу и пробую импортировать новую (100Mb), после 2-3 минут импорта вылетает ошибка:

> 500 - The request timed out.
>   The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

Пробовал указывать `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT: 3600` в настройках приложения, ошибка не ушла.

В чем может быть причина?